# SQL remove multiple time stamp from any part of a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a text field that contains multiple datetime stamps and I need to remove just the time stamp.  There is also text with carriage returns in this field.  I want to maintain text, date, and carriage returns.

Anyone have experience with this and can share the select to accomplish this?

Here is an example of the textfield :

```
[10/19/2015 5:24:02 PM Tech1] Repaired heaters [10/21/2015 8:36:28 AM Tech1] CHECKED ALL HEATER OPERATION
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: always 2 time stamps?

Comment: Not always.  It could be more than 2

Comment: Is the date/time format absolutely consistent or are there various formats, e.g. 24-hour time, day of the week, ...?

Comment: Hint... split string function then substring.... then stuff

Comment: the datetime format is consistent

Comment: Please add the expected output from the example you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way with `STUFF` and a splitter function, taking into account single and double digit hours.

```
declare @table table (vars varchar(4000))
insert into @table
values
('[10/19/2015 5:24:02 PM Tech1] Repaired heaters' + char(10) + '[10/21/2015 12:36:28 AM Tech1] CHECKED ALL HEATER OPERATION' + char(13) + '[10/22/2015 3:36:28 PM Tech1] somethingelse')
,('[11/19/2015 5:24:02 PM Tech1] asdfsdaf  [11/21/2015 8:36:28 AM Tech1] dddddddddddd [11/22/2015 3:36:28 PM Tech1] yyyyyyyyy')
,('[1/19/2015 11:24:02 PM Tech1] here went something  [09/21/2015 08:36:28 AM Tech1] Tech 1 did something else[11/22/2015 10:36:28 PM Tech1] last')

;with cte as(
select
    vars
    ,RN = dense_rank() over (order by vars)
    --,Item
    ,Item = '[' + stuff(Item,charindex(' ',Item), 3 + case when charindex(' AM ',Item) = 0 then charindex(' PM ',Item) else charindex(' AM ',Item) end  - charindex(' ',Item),'')
from
    @table
    cross apply
    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(vars,'[')
where
    Item <>'')



select distinct
    vars
    ,RemovedTime =
                STUFF((
                      SELECT ' ' + c2.Item
                      FROM cte c2
                      WHERE c.RN = c2.RN
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from
    cte c
```

The splitter can be found in [Jeff Moden's Article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Misunderstood the requirement, updated my solution based on comments below.

For this you will need [PatternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/).

```
declare @table table (someid int identity, somestring varchar(1000));
insert @table(somestring) values 
('[10/19/2015 5:24:02 PM Tech1] Repaired heaters [10/21/2015 8:36:28 AM Tech1] CHECKED ALL HEATER OPERATION'),
('[02/28/2015 5:24:02 PM Tech1] Repaired more stuff [12/01/2015 2:36:28 AM Tech1] CHECKED ALL HEATER OPERATION');

with parseMe as
(
  select 
    someid, 
    ItemNumber,
    Item = case 
           when Item like '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' then '<exclude>' 
           else replace(replace(item, ' AM ',''), ' PM ', '') end
  from @table t
  cross apply dbo.PatternSplitCM(t.somestring, '[0-9:/]')
)
select
  someid,
  newString = 
    replace((
      select item+''
      from parseMe p2 
        where p1.someid = p2.someid 
      order by ItemNumber
      for xml path(''), type
    ).value('.', 'varchar(1000)'), '<exclude>','')
from parseMe p1
group by someid;
```

Comment: This replaces the entire datetime stamp, not just the time portion.

Comment: and if there were braces anywhere else in the string, that wasn't part of the time stamp, it'd remove those too...

Comment: @scsimon I updated my solution based on your comments