# Strip Out Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My TSQL is pretty rusty and I could not find the exact answer I was looking for or it was over my head. I have a requirement to strip certain characters out of a file name that is being loaded within SSIS. I have the file name and load is doing great, it's just stripping certain characters from file name/string. Lets just call it a string.

Format of string :

```
REPORT-date-XYZ-strip me out-XYZ-BATCH.csv
```

Examples :

```
REPORT-20170725-XYZ-YOURMYHERO-XYZ-BATCH.csv
REPORT-20170725-XYZ-YOURMYHERO2-XYZ-BATCH.csv
```

Can this be done? Can someone point me in the right direction. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little sample using XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('REPORT-20170725-XYZ-YOURMYHERO-XYZ-BATCH.csv')
,('REPORT-20170725-XYZ-YOURMYHERO2-XYZ-BATCH.csv')


Select Pos4 = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace([SomeCol],'-','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Pos4
YOURMYHERO
YOURMYHERO2
```

Comment: You're pretty flawless with this method.

Comment: I was surprised you didn't finish this question too. Right up your alley. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45823406/6167855

Comment: @scsimon Lost interes, and I had a feeling it would have be a "Rabbit Hole"

Answer (score 0):

If everything is fixed length and consistent, it's pretty straightforward with [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql), I would build a new string with what you want to keep, i.e. SUBSTRING(s,1,6) + SUBSTRING(s,16,10), etc...
If it's not consistent, you'll find yourself doing lots of [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql)
to find the markers, like the hyphens.

It's clumsy, but it can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another method with `LEFT`, and `RIGHT`and `SUBSTRING` with [Cappelletti's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti) test data.

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('REPORT-20170725-XYZ-YOURMYHERO-XYZ-BATCH.csv')
,('REPORT-20170725-XYZ-YOURMYHERO2-XYZ-BATCH.csv')

select
    ReturnCol = substring(right(SomeCol,len(someCol) - len(left(SomeCol,20))),1,CHARINDEX('-',right(SomeCol,len(someCol) - len(left(SomeCol,20))))-1)
from
    @YourTable
```

**RETURNS**

```
ReturnCol
-----------
YOURMYHERO
YOURMYHERO2
```

Answer (score 0):

A way is to use `parsename`:

```
select
     parsename(replace(txt,'-XYZ-','.'), 3) stripedOut
from
    yourTable;
```

[`[SQL Fiddle Demo]`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4016)

Comment: Note that the `object_name` parameter to the `PARSENAME` function is of type `SYSNAME` which is defined as `NVARCHAR(128)` and not nullable.